# Less known Mathematician with interesting life and work history?

Tags: math-history

Our class has to present a little talk on some mathematician's life and his work (about 15-20 minutes). It was first come first choose and thus most of the big guns are already taken like Gauss, Newton, Euler, Fermat, Abel, Galois, Ramanujan, Riemann, Bernoulli family etc.

Then I thought that almost every one with Masters in Math knows about these mathematicians and their famous work. So why not pick a mathematician who has done some really interesting and important work but has somehow remained obscure.

I have read a little about Niccolò Fontana Tartaglia in Cox's book on Galois Theory but not sure if he will have enough history available and how important his work was.  Also among lady mathematicians, I thought of Noether and Germain, but they are also well known.

Can someone suggest some historical figure who somehow escaped major fame despite good work and should be applauded time to time.

Thanks!

Comment: Well...he didn't exactly escape major fame (I believe something like 10,000 people attended his funeral!), but he doesn't seem to be taken on your list: Shiing-Shen Chern.

Comment: Definitely not small but unmentioned: was Erdős taken?

Comment: Also interesting: Hassler Whitney, who was not only a terrific mathematician, but also an accomplished mountain climber and musician.

Comment: Godel has an interesting life. He went to America and was told by his friends not to talk about some logical flaw he had found in American Constitution but when he was interviewed to get American citizenship he told his doubts about the possibility for US to become legally a dictatorship, but nothing serious happened as long as I know.

Comment: Women: [Sofia Kovalevskaya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sofia_Kovalevskaya); see Michèle Audin, [Remembering Sofya Kovalevskaya](https://books.google.it/books?id=sfqMyhrVuu8C&printsec=frontcover), Springer (2011) and [Maria Gaetana Agnesi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maria_Gaetana_Agnesi); see C.Truesdell, [Maria Gaetana Agnesi](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41133864?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) (1989).

Comment: About Erdos I read his biography: he was always doped (amphetamines)! And he was always guest of his colleagues who were honoured to have such a genius as a guest... their wife and families much less :)

Comment: Instead of Tartaglia, see [Gerolamo Cardano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerolamo_Cardano) and Øystein Ore, [Cardano, the Gambling Scholar](https://books.google.it/books?id=i6ArDgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), Princeton UP, 1953.

Comment: @AndrewTawfeek Erdos seems great. Have you read any of his biographies? Which one should I look up. He must have many. I can also talk about Erdos number. It will be fun.

Comment: Oh, another that came to mind is Cantor! Also not your list.

Comment: Oh yeah man, but Cantor could be taken. I am sure that Erdos isn't though.

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth Read "The Man Who Only Loved Numbers" for a general gist of the person he was. I'll let someone else recommend a good properly biography, I don't know a good one.

Comment: Alexander Grothendieck? Nikolai Luzin? Andrey Kolmogorov?

Comment: Cauchy maybe...? Well known but not generally the first to come to mind

Comment: @johndoe He is taken.

Comment: Bertrand Russell is interesting too for being a philosoph a mathematician and a great writer    Maryam Mirzakhani a lady in mathematics

Comment: Are Turing, Laplace, Fourier, Hilbert, Riemann taken?

Comment: Taniyama for his conjecture  and Seki Takakazu known to be first to discover Bernouilli's numbers and many others results

Comment: ThanKs guys. I am deleting the question in a bit. I started reading Erdos' biography ''My Brain is open'' and he is the most interesting mathematician I have ever read about. I will present his life. More people need to know about his greatness. Thanks alot everyone for suggestions. Good day

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth why are you deleting?

Comment: As there is one closed vote, It might be off topic. Or it isn't? Also @AndrewTawfeek you can make Erdos an answer here, I ll gladly accept.

Comment: Kazimierz Kuratowski and Stefan Banach, probably amongst other Polish mathematicians. Also Pavel Alexandrov and Pavel Urysohn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paul Erdős is a wonderful choice. Anyone can edit this to add more sources if they so chose, but here's a small list:

- *My Brain is Open* (Book)
- *The Main Who Only Loved Numbers* (Book)
- *N is a Number* (Documentary)

Comment: Yes that documentary is "N is a number". It is wonderful. I have seen it in past.

Answer (score 3):

"escaped major fame" is relative, varies from man to man. So for me, my choices are Georg Cantor, Oscar Zariski, Minkowski, Atiyah or Shankar Abhayankar.

A very good reference for studying different 'classical' mathematicians' life is "Men of Mathematics" by E.T.Bell.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Grigori Perelman is one of those mathimaticians. He was chosen to be awarded 
 for his proving of Poincare Conjecture, but declined the prizes of European Mathematical Society, Fields Medal and 1 mln dollars, believing his efforts to prove the Conjecture was not significant than Richard Hamilton's. Eventually he withdrew from the mathematics, because he was dissatisfied with the ethical standards of the field of mathematics and some mathematicians (who were against his achieving of those prizes and competed with him to gain those rewards after the Conjecture was proved (he was trying to prove that hypothesis for more than 5 years)). Nowadays, not much (or, maybe nothing) is known about him, and there are many lies regarding this person.